# ¿Como puedo hacer un left join de un array con json_array_elements_text en postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonarray

estoy intentando hacer traducción de textos, tengo una tabla i18n en donde a través de códigos obtenidos de la tabla codigosT hago traducciones, estoy intentando hacer un left join a un campo de tipo json de la tabla codigosT el cual es el siguiente:

[image: campo tipo json]

en la otra tabla tengo la traduccion de los textos para esto utilizo dos campos, code y message.

[image: campos para traducción]

hasta ahora no he tenido éxito con el left join, agradeceria su ayuda.

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Este es el contenido del campo attributes que estoy tratando de enviar a la tabla i18n, los códigos (preset.template.attendance.tag.dsc) son los que recibe i18n en en la columna code y en la columna de message es donde aparece la traducción, esa columna también pertenece a la tabla i18n

```
{"tags":["preset.template.attendance.tag.dsc","preset.template.tracing.tag.dsc","preset.template.control.tag.dsc","preset.template.field.tag.dsc","preset.template.incentives.tag.dsc","preset.template.puntuality.tag.dsc","preset.template.route.tag.dsc","preset.template.route.compliance.tag.dsc","preset.template.workplan.tag.dsc"]
```

por medio dejson_array_elements_text() puedo obtener todos los códigos de "tags" que están en la columna attributes de la **tabla codigosT**

```
select json_array_elements_text("attributes"->'tags') as tags from codigosT;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con eso es con lo que quiero hacer el join para poder obtener las traduciones de la **tabla i18n** en donde el match lo va a hacer con la columna **code**

Ejemplo si yo hago la consulta a la **tabla i18n** por medio del primer código de la tabla anterior

```
select code, message from i18n where code = 'preset.template.attendance.tag.dsc';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en mi caso necesitaría hacer un left join a la tabla i18n enviando todo el arreglo de códigos de la tabla codigosT en su **campo attributes** donde se encuentra el atributo **"tags"** que contiene todos los códigos a enviar.

Comment: por favor pon más datos para ver lo que quieres pues no veo el atributo por el cual hacer el join, imagino que dentro del json esté el atributo y el valor para hacer el join con la otra tabla, pero no logro verlo

Comment: Que tal Anthony muchas gracias por la ayuda, acabo de actualizar mi pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer la consultas de los tag en una subconsulta, para hacerle el left join, algo como esto(ahí puedes ir jugando con los join que requieras):

```
select code, message from stoiii_config.i18n  left join (select json_array_elements_text("attributes"->'tags') as tags from codigosT  ) sub on (stoiii_config.i18n.code=sub.tags)
```

o usar una CTE como esto:

```
with sub as  (select json_array_elements_text("attributes"->'tags') as tags from codigosT  ) 

select code, message from stoiii_config.i18n  left join sub on (code=tags)
```

Comment: Que tal Anthony agradezco mucho tu ayuda, use las consultas pero al parecer me trae toodo lo que hay en i18n, no unicamente los códigos de los tags

Comment: Debes hacer algun filtro con los where seguramente, pero esa es la idea para hacer los left join, saludos

Comment: ok pruebo y estaré informando en unos momentos, muchas gracias